# How to automatically adjust zoom to accommodate all markers in Google Maps Compose?

Tags: kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose, google-maps-compose

Google Maps Compose library provides `cameraPositionState`  to accomodate 1 location with zoom using below code

```
val singapore = LatLng(1.35, 103.87)
val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
position = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(singapore, 10f)
}
GoogleMap(
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState)
```

How to accomplish the same wit multiple locations ? I have a list of locations and I want to initialise  `GoogleMap` to display all location markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `LatLngBounds.builder()` to create a minimum bound based on a set of `LatLng` points, then use `cameraPositionState.move()` to update the camera to the specified bounds

Instead of using `LatLngs` to specify the camera position, you can use `LatLngBounds` instead as arguments to the `CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngBounds()` documented here: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#public-static-cameraupdate-newlatlngbounds-latlngbounds-bounds,-int-padding

But you would need to have the `LatLngBounds` value first. In that case, you can use the `LatLngBounds.builder()` method to create an instance of a `bounds` to be used in your camera update.

So Let's say I have the following coordinates used to instantiate markers:

```
private val santiago = LatLng(-33.4489, -70.6693)
private val bogota = LatLng(-4.7110, -74.0721)
private val lima = LatLng(-12.0464, -77.0428)
private val salvador = LatLng(-12.9777, -38.5016)
```

Once I have that, I'll need to instantiate the builder:

```
val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.builder()
```

Create a list for the coordinates:

```
val coordinates = listOf(
            santiago,
            bogota,
            lima,
            salvador
        )
```

Then loop through it and use the `include()` method of the `builder()` through each LatLng coordinate:

```
for (coordinate in coordinates) {
    boundsBuilder.include(coordinate)
}
```

Then build it with the `build()` method and store its return value as the `bounds` to be used later on in updating your camera.

```
val bounds = boundsBuilder.build()
```

Then inside your `setContent`, if you want to update the camera on initial Load to include all the markers, you can just use the [cameraPositionState.move()](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-compose/maps-compose/com.google.maps.android.compose/-camera-position-state/index.html#-825328392%2FFunctions%2F508926583) method within a `LaunchedEffect` composable. And it would look something like this:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = true ){
    cameraPositionState.move(
        update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100)
    )
}
```

Notice that the `cameraPositionState.move()` method has an `update` parameter. That's where you just have to put the `bounds` value obtained earlier by making the `update` value into `CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(BOUNDS_VALUE_HERE, PADDING_VALUE_HERE)`

Here's a sample implementation that you can try where I also added a button for you to test the camera update outside the initial load:

```
private val santiago = LatLng(-33.4489, -70.6693)
private val bogota = LatLng(-4.7110, -74.0721)
private val lima = LatLng(-12.0464, -77.0428)
private val salvador = LatLng(-12.9777, -38.5016)
private val center = LatLng(-18.000, -58.000)
private val defaultCameraPosition1 = CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(center, 2f)

class StackOverflowSample : ComponentActivity(), OnMapsSdkInitializedCallback {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext, MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST, this)
        val boundsBuilder = LatLngBounds.builder()

        val coordinates = listOf(
            santiago,
            bogota,
            lima,
            salvador
        )

        for (coordinate in coordinates) {
            boundsBuilder.include(coordinate)
        }
        val bounds = boundsBuilder.build()
        setContent {
            // Observing and controlling the camera's state can be done with a CameraPositionState
            val cameraPositionState = rememberCameraPositionState {
                position = defaultCameraPosition1
            }
            val mapProperties by remember {
                mutableStateOf(MapProperties(mapType = MapType.NORMAL))
            }
            val marker1State = rememberMarkerState(position = santiago)
            val marker2State = rememberMarkerState(position = bogota)
            val marker3State = rememberMarkerState(position = lima)
            val marker4State = rememberMarkerState(position = salvador)

            // Drawing on the map is accomplished with a child-based API
            val markerClick: (Marker) -> Boolean = {
                Log.d(TAG, "${it.title} was clicked")
                cameraPositionState.projection?.let { projection ->
                    Log.d(TAG, "The current projection is: $projection")
                }
                false
            }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Button(onClick = {
                    cameraPositionState.move(
                        update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100)
                    )
                }) {
                    Text("Update Camera")
                }
                Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    LaunchedEffect(key1 = true ){
                        cameraPositionState.move(
                            update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 100)
                        )
                    }
                    GoogleMap(
                        modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize(),
                        googleMapOptionsFactory = {
                            GoogleMapOptions().mapId("DEMO_MAP_ID")
                        },
                        cameraPositionState = cameraPositionState,
                        properties = mapProperties,
                        onPOIClick = {
                            Log.d(TAG, "POI clicked: ${it.name}")
                        }
                    ) {

                        val textView = TextView(this@AdvancedMarkersActivity)
                        textView.text = "Hello!!"
                        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
                        textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW)

                        AdvancedMarker(
                            state = marker4State,
                            onClick = markerClick,
                            collisionBehavior = 1,
                            iconView = textView,
                            title="Marker 4"
                        )

                        val pinConfig = PinConfig.builder()
                            .setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA)
                            .setBorderColor(Color.WHITE)
                            .build()

                        AdvancedMarker(
                            state = marker1State,
                            onClick = markerClick,
                            collisionBehavior = 1,
                            pinConfig = pinConfig,
                            title="Marker 1"
                        )

                        val glyphOne = PinConfig.Glyph("A", Color.BLACK)
                        val pinConfig2 = PinConfig.builder()
                            .setGlyph(glyphOne)
                            .build()

                        AdvancedMarker(
                            state = marker2State,
                            onClick = markerClick,
                            collisionBehavior = 1,
                            pinConfig = pinConfig2,
                            title="Marker 2"
                        )

                        val glyphImage: Int = ic_menu_myplaces
                        val descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(glyphImage)
                        val pinConfig3 = PinConfig.builder()
                            .setGlyph(PinConfig.Glyph(descriptor))
                            .build()

                        AdvancedMarker(
                            state = marker3State,
                            onClick = markerClick,
                            collisionBehavior = 1,
                            pinConfig = pinConfig3,
                            title="Marker 3"
                        )

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun onMapsSdkInitialized(renderer: MapsInitializer.Renderer) {
        when (renderer) {
            MapsInitializer.Renderer.LATEST -> Log.d("MapsDemo", "The latest version of the renderer is used.")
            MapsInitializer.Renderer.LEGACY -> Log.d("MapsDemo", "The legacy version of the renderer is used.")
            else -> {}
        }
    }
}
```